# Как сделать div в форме прямоугольной трапеции?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать такой div?
Объясните, пожалуйста, как делать это с помощью `shape-inside: polygon()`. Не понимаю, как правильно прописать `x1y1`,`x2y2`,`x3y3`,`x4y4`. C какого угла идёт отсчёт, в каких единицах измерять координаты?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6s2zpwz7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.hh {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
}

.hh:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="hh"></div>
```

Если я правильно вас понял. Или должен быть принципиально `<div>`?

**P. S.:** Теперь о том, как это работает.

1. Всё основано на том, что угловой стык границ производится под углом в 45°. При этом цвет и прозрачность границы не имеет значения, стык (или место под него) всё равно будет иметь скос.

   ```css
   div {
     width: 42pt;
     height: 42pt;
     border: 2em solid;
     border-color: orange lightgreen blue transparent;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div></div>
   ```
2. Псевдоэлемент `.hh:after` — это квадрат со стороной в высоту основного элемента (`.hh`), размещённый по правую сторону от этого элемента. С помощью эффекта, описанного в пункте 1, данный квадрат был превращён в треугольник.

   ```css
   .hh {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
     width: 300px;
     position: relative;
     height: 2em;
   }

   .hh:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     width: 2em;
     height: 100%;
     left: 100%;
     top: 0;
     border: 1em solid red;
     border-color: red transparent transparent red;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="hh"></div>
   ```

Comment: расскажите за счет чего такой эффект получается

Comment: @perfect, расширил ответ

Comment: @Arhad большое вам спасибо. все понятно.